# jQuery: using click only on single element: using .slideToggle and .nextUntil to hide and show all sorts of content on click of a mouse

Tags: jquery-selectors, visibility, jquery, jquery-effects

Heys!

Ill cut right to the subject, here's the jquery code:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.entry-content h1').nextUntil('h1').hide().prev().click(function () {
        jQuery(this).nextUntil('h1').slideToggle();

});});
```

here's the html:

```
<div class="entry-content>
   <h1>Header 1</h1>
   <p>Paragraph 1</p>
   <ul>
      <li>Text</li>
      <li>Some more text</li>
   </ul>
   <h1>Some Images and a div</h1>
   <img src="image.jpg">
   <div class="somediv">
     <!--Some stuff -->
   </div>
   <h2>InBetween header</h2>
   <p>text</p>
   <ul>
      <il>text</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Now this works almost like its supposed to, on toggle the content under the h1s slide visible and when toggle again, they slide up. BUT the problem is that the efect happens also when clicking on an image of h2. I've tried to search the net for this, but havent got the answer yet :/ i'd much appriciate the help :) Simpe little script, for a page with loads of content of different kind that have "InBetween" h1's to shorten the page by hiding the content under them, and showing when clicked.

Comment: You are missing a closing " after the "entry-content class.

Comment: You are missing a closing tag on the img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Julian who made me work a little harder to solve out the problem ;)

Here's the code which now works like its supposed to : Applies click only on the h1 element :) the problem was, I applied click to all elements, thx jul :)

Here's the working jQuery (done for wp, so conflicted-mode on, if im correct)

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.entry-content h1').css('cursor' , 'pointer').click(function () {
    jQuery(this).nextUntil('h1').slideToggle();
    }).nextUntil('h1').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ulle, Your code is working as expected.
Please see the following extract defining the next until function

*Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .nextUntil() method allows us to search through the successors of these elements in the DOM tree, stopping when it reaches an element matched by the method's argument. The new jQuery object that is returned contains all following siblings up to but not including the one matched by the .nextUntil() selector.
If the selector is not matched or is not supplied, all following siblings will be selected; in these cases it selects the same elements as the .nextAll() method does when no filter selector is provided.*

You can find the full definition [here](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

You have attached the Click event to all the following siblings.

Comment: Thx m8 :) I shall try to deattach the event from everything else, except h1 :)

Comment: Resolved this, thanks for the help :) here's mycode which works now, like i want it to.

jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.entry-content h1').css('cursor' , 'pointer').click(function () {
        jQuery(this).nextUntil('h1').slideToggle();
  }).nextUntil('h1').hide();
  
   $("#info li a[href$=.pdf]").after("<img src='images/small_pdf_icon.gif' align='absbottom' />");
 });

Comment: @Ulle well done. You can answer your own question and format the code so that others can read it more easily. If you prefer you can accept my answer. Enjoy life.

Comment: @Ulle another option I am not sure that you have yet, I think you do is you can edit your own question and add the "correct" code so others can learn, and copy paste for their own needs.